# New notification coming below old notification in the tray

Tags: android, notifications

I have two notifications. Upon posting the 1st notification, it comes on the top of the tray. When I post the 2nd notification, it comes below the first notification. Ideally it should come on top of the first notification. I am using same priority for both notifications.

TargetSdkVersion =26, CompileSdkVersion = 26 and Support Library Version = 26.1.0

Please check the code.

```
int firstNotifyId = 1;
String channelId = "Default";

final NotificationCompat.Builder firstBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
    .setContentTitle("Creating First Notification")
    .setContentText("Creating First Notification")
    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);

int secondNotifyId = 2;
final NotificationCompat.Builder secondBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId)
    .setContentTitle("Creating Second Notification")
    .setContentText("Creating Second Notification")
    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);

findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(firstNotifyId, firstBuilder.build());
  }
});

findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(secondNotifyId, secondBuilder.build());
  }
});
```

Checked on Android 6 and Android 7.1. and found that the behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

(I do not have enough points to put this in a comment)

The notifications are being issued based on OnClick event.

In the question you have not mentioned about the sequence of the button clicks.

Can you share an image of how the buttons have been placed? Are button1 and button2 on different activity pages or are they placed in the same layout?

Is there possibility of user clicking button 2 first? Please share more what the app looks like in a video, or probably rest of the code.

Comment: This is my sample project in which I am clicking button1 first and then clicking button2